# Convergence of $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{(\log(\log(n))^2}{n(\log(n))^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to show that the series $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{(\log(\log(n))^2}{n(\log(n))^2}$$
converges.

I'm trying to find some upper bound for it, since the tests i've used so far did not lead to any useful conclusion. I think that a good upper bound might be the series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\log(n))^{1+\epsilon}}$, for $\epsilon >0$ because then i could use the fact that the series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges. Therefore i tried to approximate the expression $(\log \log n)^2$ to something like

$$(\log \log n)^2 \le (\log n)^{1+\delta}$$

for some $\delta > 0$ but without success. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** for $n$ big enough,
$$
(\log \log n)^2 < \sqrt{\log n
}
$$
Now use the fact that $$
\sum \frac 1{n(\log n)^{3/2}}<\infty
$$

Comment: Thank you for your time. Are you sure that $(\log \log n)^2 < \sqrt{\log n}$? Am i misinterpreting something? I tried to [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5B%28log+log%28x%29%29%5E2%2C+sqrt%28log%28x%29%29%2C+2%3Cx%3C250%5D) both functions, but i get $(\log \log n) > \sqrt{\log n}$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Yes i am sure. Put n=e^e^t before plot.